# Bit Math - Assigning 2 opposite bits (10 or 01) to a number in a single operation no matter what the original number is

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, stm32

Let's say I have a binary number `X`. Is it possible to set 2 bits in the number to either `10` or `01` in a single operation *irrespective* of the value of `X`?

This is possible for single bits. I can set a bit to `1` or `0` no matter what the original number is using:

```
x |= (1 << bit_position) // Ensures bit at bit_position is 1 always.
```

and

```
x &= ~(1 << bit_position) // Ensures bit at bit_position is 0 always.
```

I expand on this to set 2 bits which are either `11` or `00`. But is there an operation that allows me to set them to `10` or `01` in a single operation without depending on the value of `X`?

```
x ??= ??(0b01 << bit_position)
```

The `??` is the parts I can't figure out.

Note that I don't want to toggle the bits. Just set the relevant ones to `01` or `10`.

Comment: What do you mean by "single operation"?  A single line of C code, a single C operator, a single CPU instruction, an atomic operation, or what?

Comment: I mean a single line of C Code. I've been using 2 lines for every 2 bits that need to be set for the same register and it's affecting my code readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't have that form though.  You'll have to mask out the bits you want to change from one byte and the bits you want to keep from the other.

```
// put 0 in bit 2 and 1 in bit 3

byte mask = 0b00001100;  // The bits I want to play with
byte pattern = 0b00001000;  // doesn't matter what any bit but 2 and 3 are

someByte = ((pattern & mask) | (somebyte & ~mask));
```

Comment: Brilliant - answers so many questions. Is this a standard pattern used in bitmath? What is it called? Also, for the last line, I think you meant `someByte = ((pattern & mask) | (somebyte & ~mask));`

Comment: Thanks, yes I fixed it.  It has no name.  It's just the simplest piece of bitmath I could come up with off the top of my head to do what you asked.  That's what you do with this stuff.  It's not memorize a bunch of patterns.  You learn how the things work and work it out.  I thought if I have just the 1's from the positions I want and can make those positions 0's in the target byte then I just or them together.  I'm sure there are other ways to skin that cat.

Comment: Perfect for my needs thanks, I need to read up more on masking.

Comment: Some background on this, using this for the STM32411RET6 chip. Trawling through the obscure macros in the header files, seems like they are using a slightly different pattern - `someByte = (pattern | (someByte & ~mask))`. It looks like this is more efficient since it has one less operation, but it seems to require having the "don't care" bits in the `pattern` to be 0. Your approach is much better though, more idiot proof.

Comment: The reason mine had the error originally is because I started it out like that and decided to add the pattern where the bits didn't matter just to make it a little more general solution.  This way you pick which two bits of the pattern to put in. If it were always then same two bits then sure, making them 0's and not needing the mask is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

And more general way

```
uint32_t SetBits(uint32_t InitialValue, uint32_t pattern, int pos, int nbits)
{
 uint32_t mask = (((1 << nbits) - 1) << pos); 
 InitialValue &= ~mask;
 return InitialValue | (pattern & mask)
}
```

or in the single operation:

```
return (InitialValue & ~(((1 << nbits) - 1) << pos)) | (pattern & (((1 << nbits) - 1) << pos))
```

You do not need to worry about multiple mask calculation appearance in this formula. The compiler will calculate it only once.

Comment: Wow this is great! I love how you even create the mask right there in the function. I'm guessing the last statement can also be specified as a `#define` macro.